# Do Italians close a conversation with some kind of salute?

Tags: greeting

I am wondering whether it is polite or typical for an Italian person to say 'bye' or 'ciao' at the end of a phone call or when they leave the house.

I know an Italian who never signs-off on a phone call, they just hang-up and they also don't say good-bye when they leave.

Is this typical or is this person just impolite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty unusual and impolite, and also shows an ignorance of at least one of the [functions of language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakobson%27s_functions_of_language).

As for which way to close a conversations, friends or close colleagues will use a normal *Ciao* (there is a recent custom of closing a phone call with a sequence of generally three *ciao*s). People who are in less intimate relation would say *Arrivederci* (even if *A risentirci* would be more correct), *A domani* (“till tomorrow”, if that's the case) etc.

*Bye* or words in other languages can happen, but it would be an unusual and joking way of speaking.

More or less all of the above (but for the thrice-repeated *ciao*) holds for meeting in person, for when you leave a shop etc.

Answer (score 5):

It is not normal to *sbattere/chiudere/riattaccare il telefono in faccia* (hanging up a phone call) nor [*andarsene alla chetichella/all'inglese*](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_107.html) (slipping away quietly without saying goodbye).
I personally find strange many TV series where they *never* say goodbye at the phone, and most of them are American.

Although I must say that in some circumstances it could be normal if they are work related calls and the job implies making a lot of these calls especially between the same parties so that saying hello+goodbye every 5 minutes for a call would actually take away productive time.

Answer (score 2):

Usually is typical for an Italian person to say goodbye with "ciao" or "ci sentiamo (dopo, domani,...)" at the end of a phone call or with "arrivederci" or "ci vediamo" when leaving the house; it also depends whether it is a formal situation or not.

Obviously it is impolite to hang-up without saying goodbye or some kind of salutation, but that's true no matter what nationality you are.

Moreover, regarding some formal ways of signing off a phone call you can find in [this blog](https://www.italianochefatica.it/it/italiano-per-stranieri-telefonata-di-lavoro-in-italiano/) some examples:

> Telefonare in italiano: come terminare una conversazione? (How to end a phone call?)
>
> 1. **Signor Bianchi, è stato un piacere parlare con lei.** – Mr. Bianchi,
>      it was nice talking with you!;
> 2. Me ne occuperò domani. – I’ll do that tomorrow.
> 3. Lo verificherò subito. – I’ll check it right away.
> 4. Le invierò il preventivo per posta. – I’ll send you an estimate by
>      mail.
> 5. Le invierò i dettagli via e-mail. – I’ll send you all details by
>      mail.
> 6. Sono in attesa di una sua conferma … – I’m waiting for your
>      confirmation...
> 7. La ringrazio per l’aiuto! **Arrivederla!** – Thank you very much for
>      your help! Goodbye!
> 8. **Arrivederla signor Bianchi, a presto!**  – Speak to you soon, Mr.
>      Bianchi!

Comment: Linguistic note: *greet* refers only to the beginning of the conversation, not the end (if you think about it, it's kind of confusing that Italian use *salutare* for both!)

Comment: @DenisNardin Thanks for your clarification (and your edit as well).